# Accessing the database when connecting mongoose in Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

have a rather elementary question about accessing a Mongoose database in node. So in my server file, I have made the necessary imports and everything, and I have connected to the database like so:

```
mongoose.connect(myURL, function(err) {if(err){console.log(err)}})
```

When I go to the terminal for the database, it says that it is connected to myUrl, and then I can do stuff like:

```
db.nameOfCollection.find("whatever")
```

And get what I want. However, now I wanna do the same thing in my Node server file, and I am extremely confused on how to do this. When I do

```
db.collectionName.find("whatever")
```

It obviously doesn't work because db is not defined. Therefore, I imported the model for one of my collections:

```
var model = require('path/to/model')
```

And now, when I do `console.log(model.find())`, it of course doesn't give me any data, but it does say right at the bottom this:

```
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection:
   NodeCollection {
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: null,
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'nameOfCollection',
        collectionName: 'nameOfCollection',
        conn: [NativeConnection],
        queue: [],
        buffer: true,
        emitter: [EventEmitter] },
     collectionName: 'nameOfCollection' },
  _traceFunction: undefined }
```

I see that it says nameOfCollection from the database, however I am not sure how to access the collection itself. Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.JS support **non-blocking** feature and your situation will use it. So you should practice some example about **callback, promise** in Node.JS. After that, you will understand and solve it.

In your situation, after you import model:

```
var model = require('path/to/model')
```

You can access to a collection by the way:

```
model.find().then(youDataYouNeed => {
    console.log(youDataYouNeed)
}
```

Due to function `find` return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can use **.then()** and append **fulfillment handler**, where you can get data of that collection.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. Hey, I just have one more question that I couldn't find an answer to, I was wondering if you can help. Does the $max operator find the maximum (i.e. latest) times as well, or does it only work for integers/floats? When I run it, I did get dates but I am not 100% if they are the latest dates.

Comment: You can use `sort` to get max, min value instead of using `$max, $min`. You can see my code:

`MyModel.find({}).sort({timeField: -1}).limit(1).then(lastest =>  console.log(lastest)`

You can change `1` or `-1` to sort results in ascending or descending order. And you can get max or min value.